# Ruby on Rails customer-facing formbuilder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, user-input

I have a customer that wants to build their own questionnaires.  Something like WuFoo (www.wufoo.com) but more secure and contained within the app.

I've looked at Smerf (http://github.com/springbok/smerf) which provides the yaml-to-form conversion, but I'd like something the user can use to create their own forms.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using active_scaffold.  The main version has not been updated for Rails 3, but a fork at the location below has. I think it would work well for your purpose, you just need a way to grab the data and feed it in.  Here is a demo of what it looks like when it is running:

https://github.com/vhochstein/active_scaffold

Here is a demo at the top of the page:

http://demo.activescaffold.com/roles

Answer (score 0):

You could always embed Google Forms. Might be easier than reinventing the wheel. Unless you have some specific use case this doesn't cover?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not adverse to going the Javascript route the then you might consider one of the many framework plugins like the [JQuery Form Builder](http://www.botsko.net/blog/2009/04/jquery-form-builder-plugin/). From a usability perspective it seems to me that any good solution is going to involve some Javascript. There should be no reason why this approach wouldn't integrate well into a Rails backend

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this one. [Dynamic Forms](https://github.com/tcocca/dynamic_forms)

I too am looking for something very similar. What solution did you come up with?